# JMeter and data test visualization

Tags: testing, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm a novice in JMeter's world and I'm trying to get graphs with only the data used in the test, no JMeter's metrics needed.

My test case consists in many sensors sending information to a central point, which has to process this info and send a response to a consumer.

The group of sensor are a group of threads where every single sensor has it's own csv data file. The consumer is an AMQP Consumer.

I would like to save in cvs files the next:

- One file for the information sent by the every sensor with the timestamp(one file->one sensor).
- One file containing all consumer's responses.

By now, I have mess with Aggregated Report and sample_variables declared in user.properties file. In this way, Jmeter includes the variables declared in user.properties in every report.

Does JMeter fits for my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Dmitri T said, it is not possible to create charts for custom data in current JMeter version.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can precisely control what JMeter stores in .jtl results file by amending relevant [Results File Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config), for example the following entries in *user.properties* file will suppress all JMeter metrics and leave only timestamps:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=falsejmeter.save.saveservice.label=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.time=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.sent_bytes=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=false
   ```

   The same can be done using [`-J` command-line option](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.label=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.successful=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.time=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.latency=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.sent_bytes=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=false -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=false  -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
2. In order to create a separate result file per request you can use [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) listener which allows storing arbitrary metrics. You will need to add Flexible File Writer as a child of each Sampler which response you would like to store. Flexible File Writer can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T, In this way I can store what I want but I think than JMeter is not a suitable tool for my needs. After storing data in csv-jtl I want to print this graphs using JMeter. Is this posible??

Comment: As per current [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) there is no possibility to build charts for custom data, the feature will be available in [JMeter 5.0](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62166). Theoretically you can substitute one of JMeter metrics with your own data and generate charts from it, however it depends on requirements for the output.